# Log in Java with variable name?

Tags: java, debugging, logging

In a previous job, I was working in C++, and the company internal library had a logging macro where I could simply write LOG(*somevariable*), and it would output to standard out:

"*variablename*: *variablevalue*"

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this in Java?

I never thought to look at their code so I don't know how it was done.  It was really useful though!

Comment: In Netbeans, you can type `soutv` + TAB to generate a println statement that will do that.

Comment: Do you really want to log to stdout? You can emulate this, but with all the graphical debuggers and stuff available for Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Eclipse you can use the "Watch Expression"-View to watch not only variables but also Method calls. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-addwatch.htm).

If you just want to print a variable's value, you can use an Eclipse Template.
Go to `Windows->Preferences` and look for the entry `Java->Editor->Templates`. Add a new template and call it for example "printvar". Add the following to the templates body:

```
System.out.println("${variable} = "+ ${variable});
```

Typing `printvar` during coding and then pressing <kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd> will generate the entered code using `${variable}` as placeholder for the variable name. You will have to type the variable name only once, which saves time and typing.

*BTW:* The reason why you can create macros permitting syntactic sugar like LOG(variable_name) in C++, is beacuse C++ has a preprocessor: Java has none. There are implementations for Java preprocessors, but I think using one would be too much effort for such a simple problem like printing a variable's name followed by its value.

Answer (score 2):

If you type <kbd>soutv + TAB</kbd> on Intellij and Netbeans it will give you a list of variables you might want to print.

[image]

I copied this and changed it to use the logger instead with <kbd>logv + TAB</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I imagine it is short for System.OUT.println("Variable =" + variable) ;)

Comment: I see. Thought it was a key. :)

Answer (score 0):

The typical technique is to use log4j, or logback, or something. Perhaps as mediated by slf4j. This required, typically, a static variable per class, which in turn causes the log messages to tell you where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have MACRO's in java, but you could do something like this with a static method on some class.. does not have the variable name but does have the class type.

```
class DebugUtil
{
  public void static LOG(Object obj)
  {
    LOG(System.out, obj.getClass().getName(), obj);
  }

  public void static LOG(String name, Object obj)
  {
    LOG(System.out, name, obj);
  }

  public void static LOG(PrintStream ps, String name, Object obj)
  {
    ps.println(name + ":" + obj);
  }
}
```

then for usage

```
String foo = "bar";
Debug.Util.LOG(foo);
Debug.Util.LOG("foo", foo);
```